# Twitter bootstrap popover with manual click trigger. Preventing default

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to figure out how to configure multiple twitter bootstrap's popovers with a manual click.

But first, some code:

```
# bootstrap.js.coffee
# this opens a popover with new server data
$('*[data-poload]').bind 'click', ->
  $this = $(this)
  $.get $this.data('poload'), (d) ->
    $this.popover
      content: d
      html: true
      title: $this.parents("tr").data("title")
    .popover 'show'

# this handles clicks everywhere on the page and decides what to do if it finds opened popovers
$("html").click (e) ->
  $('*[data-poload]').each ->
    $(this).popover "hide" if not ($(this).is(e.target) or $(this).has(e.target).length > 0) and $(this).siblings(".popover").length isnt 0 and $(this).siblings(".popover").has(e.target).length is 0
```

This is the popoverable link. I have hundreds of these on the same page with different data-poload attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-poload="/resources/some-id/popover">Text</a>
```

My server will respond with some html to this request `/resources/some-id/popover` that goes in the popover body.

What I want to happen if I click a popover:

- Open the popover (after the server responds)
- Don't scroll to top of the page
- Don't close if I click on the popover's body (there are some links there)
- Close the previous popover (if opened)

If I click anywhere else:

- Close the previous popover (if opened)

The problem:

- If I click a popover it will scroll to the top of the page (typical click propagation)
- If I re-click the same link to open the popover, that popover will get broken and will not be able to open it again. It opens and closes right after.

I tried by putting a `return false` like so

```
# bootstrap.js.coffee
$('*[data-poload]').bind 'click', ->
  $this = $(this)
  $.get $this.data('poload'), (d) ->
    $this.popover
      content: d
      html: true
      title: $this.parents("tr").data("title")
    .popover 'show'
  false
```

but that won't work because the next js bit will not get triggered. The one that's supposed to close the other popovers. Clicking everywhere else works
of course.